# Mikro ORM Virtual entity not being present in service

Tags: nestjs, computed-properties, mikro-orm

I have the following NestJS route set up:

```
  @Get(':id')
  async getUserInfo(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const res = await this.userService.findOneByField(id);
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  }
```

Using this service:

```
 findOneByField(args) {
    return this.em.findOneOrFail(User, args);
  }
```

Which fetches the following entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'uuid', defaultRaw: 'uuid_generate_v4()' })
  id: string;

  @OneToOne(() => MutedUser, (mutedUser) => mutedUser.user)
  mutedUser!: MutedUser;

  @Property({ persist: false })
  get isMuted() {
    return !!this.mutedUser;
  }
}
```

Now, when logging the `res` in the controller, the `isMuted` virtual property does not exist, but in Postman when i return res it **does** exist. Is this how MikroORM works? Or is there something going wrong here

Comment: Depends on how are you logging it, if you would use a simple `console.log`, the property should be there, but I guess you log it via some nestjs logger, and that might be ignoring getters.

Comment: Hmm actually it is not there, this seems to be a bug in the custom inspect method that ignores them, will take a closer look.

Comment: Correct,  I'm using console.log. The problem is that I need to access the virtual prop in nestJS, not in my frontend

Comment: You can access it anywhere you want, this is a logging issue, the getter is there.